# Can't login to Enthought/Canopy

Tags: python, enthought, canopy

I have [Enthought/Canopy](https://enthought.com/) installed on my Windows7X64.
It works fine until I try to login to Enthought server through Package Manager in order to install some additional packages. Then the next error occurs:

"WSGI Proxy "Server" Error.
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"

[image]

I have no proxy, just direct internet connection.
Is there any workaround for this bug?

Comment: Replied to private support request, with request for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Quickest workaround is to switch OS's russian locale to english one.